# ES6: harmony-proxies: Why does `tracedObj.squared(9)` return undefined?

Tags: javascript, proxy, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony, es6-proxy

Why does `tracedObj.squared(9)` return undefined?

This likely has something to do with the scope of `obj` being in the wrong scope for it's `this` call in `squared` after it calls a method on it's own object.

## Code

```
"use strict";
var Proxy = require('harmony-proxy');

function traceMethodCalls(obj) {
   let handler = {
       get(target, propKey, receiver) {
            const origMethod = target[propKey];
            return function(...args) {
                let result = origMethod.apply(this, args);
                console.log(propKey + JSON.stringify(args) + ' -> ' + JSON.stringify(result));
            };
       }
   };
   return new Proxy(obj, handler);
}

let obj = {

     multiply(x, y) {
        return x * y;
     },
     squared(x) {
        return this.multiply(x, x);
     }
};

let tracedObj = traceMethodCalls(obj);
tracedObj.multiply(2,7);

tracedObj.squared(9);
obj.squared(9);
```

## Output

```
multiply[2,7] -> 14
multiply[9,9] -> 81
squared[9] -> undefined
undefined
```

I'm using node v4.4.3 (is it too soon to use these?)

## Run the Code

I have to run the command like this:

`node --harmony-proxies --harmony ./AOPTest.js`

Comment: Found the code for this here: http://www.2ality.com/2015/10/intercepting-method-calls.html but I believe the author is using FF.

Comment: You never `return result;` in your replacement function?

Comment: @loganfsmyth that was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return function(...args) {
    let result = origMethod.apply(this, args);
    console.log(propKey + JSON.stringify(args) + ' -> ' + JSON.stringify(result));
};
```

is missing

```
return result;
```